# Python Setuptool Package Data By Platform

Tags: python, setuptools

I am wondering if there is way to include different files into package_data depending on windows vs linux.

Here is what I want to achieve.

At present, I have the same config file for both linux and windows. In the setup.cfg, it has:

```
[options.package_data]
my_package = 
    prod.conf
```

I want to have both prod_linux.cfg and prod_windows.cfg in the package directory and let the setuptool to rename it into the prod.cfg when the user installs the package. Something like

```
[options.package_data.linux]
my_package = 
    prod.conf = prod_linux.conf

[options.package_data.windows]
my_package = 
    prod.conf = prod_windows.conf
```

Is it possible?

Thanks